# Несколько запросов в одном GET

Tags: json, php, android, mysql

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся такой вот проблемой или google не понял, чего я хочу:
Я пишу программу для андроид. И там не все так легко в плане MySQL.
У меня есть 2 таблицы из которых я должен вывести один конечный результат.
Таблица 1. Поля:

```
{name},{id1},{num1},{id2},{num2}.
```

Таблица 2.

```
{id},{tname},{sum}.
```

К примеру, у меня есть информация о name - имя пользователя.

```
$name=$_GET[name];
```

Используя name, я должен сделать такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=$name;
```

затем используя id1, сделать запрос по id.

```
SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE id=$id1;
```

затем присвоить результат sum к любому, скажем к `sum1`, и `tname` к `tname1`.
И аналогично повторить для `id2`  и присвоить его sum к `sum1` и к `tname2`.
И вывести `sum1`, `sum2`, `tname1`, `tname2`.
Я слабо знаю PHP, но в `POST` я разобрался. В `GET` методе, знаю, что можно сделать один запрос, заполнить массив, разобрать массив и отправить по JSON на приложение. Нельзя ли это дело провернуть без get-get-get?
Вот код для одиночного запроса `GET`.

```
response = array();
require 'db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
mysql_query('SET names utf8');
$name = $_GET["name"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM users WHERE name = '$name'");

if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $product = array();
        $product["name"] = $result["name"];
        $product["id1"] = $result["id1"];
        $product["id2"] = $result["id2"];
        $product["num1"] = $result["num1"];
        $product["num2"] = $result["num2"];

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["pro"] = array();

        array_push($response["pro"], $pro);
        echo json_encode($response);
}
else{}
```

Comment: Вам никто не мешает в пределах одного запроса сделать много запросов к базе (в разумных пределах), завернуть все это в один большой json и вернуть пользователю.

Comment: да я мог, если бы имел все поля до первого запроса, как в случае post. тут другие вытекают после первого запроса.

Comment: @Madi, если пользователь должен формировать эти дополнительные данные, то одним запросом никак. Если пользователь не имеет к этому отношения, то вытягивайте в рамках того же запроса данные и обрабатывайте их дальше.